# Constants name declared with a dot (SOME.CONSTANT): how to access?

Tags: php

How do I access a constant which name was declared with a dot (eg.: *SOME.CONSTANT*), without using the "constant" function?

The main reason for that, is so I can declare a class property like this:

```
class Classname {
  public $variable = SOME.CONSTANT; // Can't use "constant('SOME.CONSTANT')" here
}
```

And yet: any particular reason I should avoid the use of dots in constant names? I just started using it so I could create some kind of "namespace" for constants, as in *AUTHCONTROL.ACCESSLEVEL.ADMIN*

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest namespacing with `_`, as in `E_USER_ERROR`, `M_PI` and so on.

Comment: Avoid dots because dots in PHP are used for concatenation. There is no way to differentiate `echo CONST.WITH.DOT;` from `echo CONST . ANOTHER . CONST;`

Comment: yeah, I thought about that, but seems more "natural" to namespace it with a `.`. if there's no other way then, sure, I will use the `_`

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using the old PHP4 style class declarations with `var`.  That is deprecated, [use PHP5 class declarations instead.](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I actually coded it with `public $something = '';`, but for some reason I posted the question with `var`. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Kolink if you want, just create an answer with your proposal and I will mark it as the accepted one. I think using `_` is the most reasonable way to create "namespaces".

Comment: Why you not using `constant('SOME.CONSTANT')`?

Comment: @harishsharma it doesn't look natural to use a function to retrieve a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to use `_` as a namespace separator in constant names. Examples include `E_USER_ERROR`, `M_PI` and so on.